# How to write JSON object keys to CSV file?

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

Currently working on a script to query some asset information from an online environment asset list. here is the script that outputs a ton of JSON object data. Ignore some of the unused imports.

(Note the method for `tenableIO` is part of the pyTenable package, but just know it returns JSON objects, so I don't necessarily need to use the `json.load` function.)

```
from pprint import pprint
from tenable.io import TenableIO
import time
import json
import os
import datetime
import csv

# filter variables to request specific assets from the api

last_month = int(time.time()) - 2629743
source_list = ["AZURE"]

# TenableIO by default uses environmental variables stored locally for api keys

tio = TenableIO()

for asset in tio.exports.assets(sources=source_list, updated_at=last_month):
    hostname = asset['hostnames']
    ipv4 = asset['ipv4s']
    print(hostname, ipv4)
```

Most of this script is directly from the tenable documentation on how to export an asset list. The bit I'm struggling with is the output of the asset JSON data.

The script seems to be parsing the json data correctly and is returning the following output as expected (using filler names and IP's as this is private data)

```
['abc123'] ['XX.XX.XX.XX']
['def456'] ['XX.XX.XX.XX']
['ghi789'] ['XX.XX.XX.XX', 'YY.YY.YY.YY', 'ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ']
```

How do I take this output and write it to a csv file? more specifically, how do I make it so that I have column 1 as hostnames, column 2 as ip addreses where multiple values are stored with their key and not as separate columns?

i.e. this table format in csv:

```
Hostnames | IP Address
1. abc123 | XX.XX.XX.XX
2. def456 | XX.XX.XX.XX
3. ghi789'| XX.XX.XX.XX
            YY.YY.YY.YY
            ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ
4. jkl123 | XX.XX.XX.XX
```

**Edit:**

Adding the JSON structure as requested:

```
{

"asset":{
"fqdn":"example.com"
"hostnames":"172.106.217.225"
"uuid":"150dee8f-6090-4a9c-907c-54a1c39ddab0"
"ipv4s":"172.156.65.8"

"operating_system":[...
]
"network_id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
"tracked":true
}
"output":"The observed version of Google Chrome is :
 Chrome/21.0.1180.90"

"plugin":{

"cve":[...
]
"cvss_base_score":9.3
"cvss_temporal_score":6.9

"cvss_temporal_vector":{...
}

"cvss_vector":{...
}
"description":"The version of Google Chrome on the remote host is prior to 48.0.2564.82 and is affected by the foll ..."
"family":"Web Clients"
"family_id":1000020
"has_patch":false
"id":9062
"name":"Google Chrome &lt; 48.0.2564.82 Multiple Vulnerabilities"
"risk_factor":"HIGH"

"see_also":[...
]
"solution":"Update the Chrome browser to 48.0.2564.82 or later."
"synopsis":"The remote host is utilizing a web browser that is affected by multiple vulnerabilities."

"vpr":{...
}
}

"port":{
"port":0
"protocol":"TCP"
}

"scan":{
"completed_at":"2018-12-31T20:59:47Z"
"schedule_uuid":"413765fb-e941-7eea-ca8b-0a79182a2806e1b6640fe8a2217b"
"started_at":"2018-12-31T20:59:47Z"
"uuid":"e2c070ae-ec37-d9ff-f003-2e89b7e5e1ab8af3a9957a077904"
}
"severity":"high"
"severity_id":3
"severity_default_id":3
"severity_modification_type":"NONE"
"first_found":"2018-12-31T20:59:47Z"
"last_found":"2018-12-31T20:59:47Z"
"state":"OPEN"
}
```

Comment: Please include a example of the JSON (synthetic data is ok) structure.

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Have you tried breaking down the problem? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I added the JSON structure to the bottom of the main post, as it's quite large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing the output to a csv is what you want, you can achieve that the python csv module

```
import csv
fields = ['Hostnames', 'IP Address']
filename = "myfile.csv"

li1 = [['abc123'],['XX.XX.XX.XX']]
li2 = [['def456'],['XX.XX.XX.XX']]
li3 = [['ghi789'],['XX.XX.XX.XX']]
li4 = [None, ['YY.YY.YY.YY']]
li5 = [None, ['ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ']]
rows = [li1, li2, li3, li4, li5]

with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:  
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)   
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    for row in rows:   
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```